# Is it possible to create a RAID from only partial disk?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, intel-rst

We have a dual boot system where we install firmare on two partitions, additionally we have a data partition. We have two disks on the system and I wonder if we can create a raid for the data partition but only use 50% of the disk space for the RAID (1).

At the moment we're using RST but could change to a normal mdadm RAID 1.

[image]

Is this setup possible?